# Is there an expression similar to the English "gut feeling" in Chinese?

Tags: word-requests, idioms, expressions

Is there a metaphor or idiom that has a similar meaning to "gut feeling", as a metaphor for "intuition" or "instinctive feeling", in Mandarin Chinese?

Answer (score 5):

The word for intuition or gut feeling is usually just rendered:

> 直觉

New Century English-Chinese also defines **gut feeling**:

> NOUN
>   直觉(相对于基于事实的观点)

Answer (score 1):

成语 along those lines from [Baidu](https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/588778223066711765.html):

料事如神, 先见之明, 不出所料, 未卜先知

Answer (score 1):

Maybe 预感? Google translates it as "hunch".